# AWS Disaster Recovery whitepaper

Tags: amazon-web-services

The link is broken https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Disaster_Recovery.pdf.

I have an error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>B80C4C4115C5CEFE</RequestId>
  <HostId>
JVaBsDqLa/6/gfpoqZyfe7lNu7ALgH/PCanmT11Bfn34UJTFaE9Rr/IMwBh6ARpNK21BdzrCzuo=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

Does anyone know where I can get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS White Papers can be downloaded from their [whitepaper site](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/?). I can confirm that it is not available right now, only AWS knows why. It will probably be available again soon.

I happen to have a version from October 2014, which was current as of October 2018 when I downloaded it. This suggests it is an older white paper that is due a refresh. I have put it on my website for download - now removed.